# How do you create a Month to Month report on the number of records with a given field value?

Tags: reporting

We have a custom field on the Account object, and we need to create a report that shows the month to month changes in the number of records that have a specific value for that custom field. Is this something that is achievable through reporting on the Account object? Or do we need to make a custom object that would only hold snapshot information for that field?

Here is an example of what we want to see:

Say the custom field is called Interest__c. It is a Picklist with 3 possible values: Low, Medium, High.
At the end of January we have 2 clients with an Interest of low, 1 with medium, 3 with high.
At the end of February we instead have 1 with low, 2 with medium, still 3 with high.
We would want a column chart report to show that in January we had 1 client with medium Interest and 3 with high, and in February those numbers changed to 2 with medium, and 3 with high. We don't care about low.

Thank you for any help you can provide!

Comment: This is the primary function of [Reporting Snapshots](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=sf.data_defining_analytic_snap.htm&type=5). Basically, look at changes of an object over time and capture those changes in another object for reporting purposes.

Comment: I think you are right @MarkPond. That sounds like exactly what I want to accomplish. If you post an answer I will accept it.